# How to "model" $\frac{6}{x-9}$

Tags: arithmetic

I'm working as a tutor and I got a question (from grade 9 no less) that reads "model: $\frac{6}{x=9}$. The only example I could get from the students was:

[image]

Which...dosn't help - how do you emulate this when downstairs can change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really unclear. The expression in your title and body don't agree. What do you mean by modeling an expression? For example, how would you model $x$?

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{6}{x-9}$?

Comment: Yes - this is exactly my confusion.  Presumably the answer looks "something" like the attached image. I don't have more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are $x$ people in a life boat. There are $6$ gallons of drinking water in the boat. $9$ of the people get swept off the boat by a big wave and drown (sorry about that). How much drinking water is left for each of the remaining people if the water is to be divided equally among them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to drive $6$ km, but you forgot to change the car's summer tires to winter tires, so you have to drive $9$ km per hour slower than usual as a safety precaution. How long will it take you to get to your destination?

Comment: Sure - can you translate this to a something like the attached image?

Comment: @Muselive No, I don't see what the image (from your student) has to do with anything. Students can make up nonsense all the time.

Comment: True, but I've gotten 4 more since this post - all with the same question and no example on how to deal with downstairs changing. This is some kind of "new" way of teaching division I think.

Comment: @Muselive Okay, I think I misunderstood at first. Is the "example" from the teacher, or an attempt at a solution by a student? In either case, what grade is this for?

Comment: Grade 9. The "example" is a solution to "model n/5", which is of course, a much nicer problem.

Comment: @Muselive So your question is not to how “model” $\frac{6}{x-9}$ (or my answer would be acceptable), but rather draw a graphical illustration of it.